# How to add message box in vb?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, messagebox

How to add message box using vb?

I get an error below when using MsgBox()

[image: Here the error]

Comment: What use could it be to call `MsgBox` in code on the server when the user is viewing your web page in a browser on a different machine? You need to learn how web programming works. If you want to prompt the user to do something in a page then that's done in JavaScript in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

VB doesn't automatically assign a string type so maybe there's the problem...

Try this:

```
Dim msg$ = "text..."
```

The above is a short version of:

```
Dim msg As String = "text..."
```

If you disable the *Option Explicit* compile option, then you can just write:

```
 msg$ = "text..."
```